# Why is Euler's formula a definition?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Even though there are proofs for Euler's formula for complex exponentials (see wikipedia for instance), it is mentioned as a "definition" in most textbooks. Why is that? 
My understanding is that a definition defines something that cannot be derived from other theorems.

Answer (score 8):

The complex exponential function needs some definition.

There are several ways one could define it:

1. Power series
2. As a solution to a differential equation
3. As the unique holomorphic extension of the real exponential function to the whole plane
4. Via the limit definition $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{z}{n})^n$
5. Via Euler's formula
6. ...

One can take any one of these as the definition.  Then you should probably prove that the other properties hold.  What is a definition and what is a theorem is, in a sense, a matter of taste.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, one might say that the _actual_ theorem is of the The-Following-Conditions-Are-Equivalent type, and we can then define the exponential function as the one that satisfies the equivalent conditions. It's just that proving _all_ of the conditions equivalent takes up so much textbook space that it's inconvenient to label it a single theorem in its own right -- and on the other hand, very convenient to define a name for the thing we're talking about _before_ we've finished proving all of the equivalences.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be mixing-up of some ideas. It's not the formula *per se* the one that needs a definition *for* the formula. It is the expression $e^x$. This expression, as mentioned by Steven, may be *defined* in various ways, which all represent the same thing. It is like the expression $e^x$ is some kind of ubiquitous expression, if you may see it that way. You may enunciate it in various ways, which in the end mean the same thing.

In the case of Euler's Formula, what we find is yet *another* (yet incredible) way to describe the idea of $e^x$. The formula may have been derived, but once again, it comes down to Earth to present another way of *defining* $e^x$!